# Screenshots with ICS are 0-byte long

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, screenshots

ICS does seem to take screenshots successfully on the Galaxy Nexus, but the files are all 0-byte long in "My Computer\Galaxy Nexus\Internal Storage\Pictures\Screenshots".

Has someone seen this? What's wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: They show up fine with my Galaxy Nexus attached to Win7. What PC/operating system type are you using? Have you got your phone set to Media Transfer Mode? (to check press the USB icon in the notification bar while connected to check).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it's in MTP mode, and I can see a list of files but they're all zero-byte long. It's on XPSP3.

Comment: Did you check the files locally on your device (e.g. with a file manager, or whether they show up correctly in the gallery app)?